# Cancel the runnable/handler in a custom view when the activity pauses

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

I have a custom view that has a blinking cursor. I make the blinking cursor using a `Handler` and posting a `Runnable` to it after a 500 milisecond delay.

When the activity that the view is in, I want to stop the blinking by removing the callbacks on the handler. However, I've noticed that when I switch to another app, the handler/runnable keep going, ie, the log says it is still blinking.

If I had control of the view I would just do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560296/3681880)

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
     super.onPause();
}
```

But my custom view will be part of a library and so I don't have control over the Activities that other developers use my custom view in.

I tried `onFocusChanged`, `onScreenStateChanged`, and `onDetachedFromWindow` but none of these work for when the user switches to another app.

Here is my code. I simplified it by removing anything not pertinent to the problem.

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

    static final int BLINK = 500;
    private Handler mBlinkHandler;

    private void init() {
        // ...
        mBlinkHandler = new Handler();

        mTextStorage.setOnChangeListener(new MongolTextStorage.OnChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(/*...*/) {
                // ...
                startBlinking();
            }
        });
    }

    Runnable mBlink = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBlinkHandler.removeCallbacks(mBlink);
            if (shouldBlink()) {
                // ...
                Log.i("TAG", "Still blinking...");
                mBlinkHandler.postDelayed(mBlink, BLINK);
            }
        }
    };

    private boolean shouldBlink() {
        if (!mCursorVisible || !isFocused()) return false;
        final int start = getSelectionStart();
        if (start < 0) return false;
        final int end = getSelectionEnd();
        if (end < 0) return false;
        return start == end;
    }

    void startBlinking() {
        mBlink.run();
    }

    void stopBlinking() {
        mBlinkHandler.removeCallbacks(mBlink);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if (focused) {
            startBlinking();
        } else {
            stopBlinking();
        }
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenStateChanged(int screenState) {
        switch (screenState) {
            case View.SCREEN_STATE_ON:
                startBlinking();
                break;
            case View.SCREEN_STATE_OFF:
                stopBlinking();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        startBlinking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        stopBlinking();
    }
}
```

Comment: hope this helps: http://androidxref.com/1.6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#6607

Comment: @pskink, good idea. I need to go back to the Android source code and study it more. Any reason you linked to the older version of `TextView` rather than the current one? Is it because it was a simpler implementation back then?

Comment: yes, exactly, now its... i dont know really how it works now (i was too lazy to dig into it) - there is something like `mEditor.makeBlink()` so probably it makes something

Comment: @pskink, I finally got around to following your suggestion and got it working. Thank you.

Comment: good, seems your project is not in a hurry (my comment was made 9 months ago) ;-)

Comment: @pskink, right, most users didn't notice the cursor blinking invisibly in the background. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by following @pskink's advice in the comments and adapted the code from [Android 1.6](http://androidxref.com/1.6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#6607). This may be an old version of Android but the blinking cursor part works well for my purposes. Overriding `onWindowFocusChanged` was the key.

My [full code](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library/blob/master/mongol-library/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/mongollibrary/MongolEditText.java) is on GitHub. Here are the pertinent parts:

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

    private boolean mCursorVisible = true;
    private Blink mBlink;
    private long mShowCursor; // cursor blink timing based on system clock
    static final int BLINK = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        mShowCursor = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (focused) {
            makeBlink();
        }
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int start = getSelectionStart();
        int end = getSelectionEnd();

        // draw the blinking cursor on top
        if (start == end && blinkShouldBeOn()) {
            canvas.drawRect(getCursorPath(start), mCursorPaint);
        }
    }

    private boolean blinkShouldBeOn() {
        if (!mCursorVisible || !isFocused()) return false;
        return (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mShowCursor) % (2 * BLINK) < BLINK;
    }
    private void makeBlink() {
        if (!mCursorVisible) {
            if (mBlink != null) {
                mBlink.removeCallbacks(mBlink);
            }

            return;
        }

        if (mBlink == null)
            mBlink = new Blink(this);

        mBlink.removeCallbacks(mBlink);
        mBlink.postAtTime(mBlink, mShowCursor + BLINK);
    }

    public void setCursorVisible(boolean visible) {
        mCursorVisible = visible;
        invalidateCursorPath();

        if (visible) {
            makeBlink();
        } else if (mBlink != null) {
            mBlink.removeCallbacks(mBlink);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);

        if (hasWindowFocus) {
            if (mBlink != null) {
                mBlink.uncancel();

                if (isFocused()) {
                    mShowCursor = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    makeBlink();
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (mBlink != null) {
                mBlink.cancel();
            }
            hideSystemKeyboard();
        }
    }

    private static class Blink extends Handler implements Runnable {
        private WeakReference<MongolEditText> mView;
        private boolean mCancelled;

        Blink(MongolEditText v) {
            mView = new WeakReference<>(v);
        }

        public void run() {
            if (mCancelled) {
                return;
            }

            removeCallbacks(Blink.this);

            MongolEditText met = mView.get();

            if (met != null && met.isFocused()) {
                int st = met.getSelectionStart();
                int en = met.getSelectionEnd();

                if (st == en && st >= 0 && en >= 0) {
                    if (met.mLayout != null) {
                        met.invalidateCursorPath();
                    }

                    postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + BLINK);
                }
            }
        }

        void cancel() {
            if (!mCancelled) {
                removeCallbacks(Blink.this);
                mCancelled = true;
            }
        }

        void uncancel() {
            mCancelled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are starting the thread separately using thread.run(), instead just make a method and call it recursively Something like this:

```
public void blink(){
     mBlinkHandler.postDelayed(mBlink, BLINK);
}
```

And in the runnable:

```
Runnable mBlink = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mBlinkHandler.removeCallbacks(mBlink);
        if (shouldBlink()) {
            // ...
            Log.i("TAG", "Still blinking...");
           blink();
        }
    }
};
```

As you are directly starting the thread using run method. So it won't stop by removing callbacks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does stop it by removing callbacks in other situations (like losing focus or closing the activity), so I don't think it is just because I start it initially with `run`.